# Given a ring with four elements, find the maximal number of elements in an ideal

Tags: ring-theory

Given a ring with four elements. What is the maximum number of elements that an ideal of this ring can have?

I think that the answer is $4$ since if $R$-the ring has an identity element, say $e$ and our ideal, say $I$ has $e$ in it, then $I$=$R$ and thus $I$ has 4 elements;

Now consider that our ring does not necessarilly has $e$. But $0$ is in $R$. Thus $R=(0,a,b,c)$. Now obviously $0$ itself is an ideal. But if I managae to find relations between the other $3$ elements, such that $a.a=a$, $a.c=c$, $a.b=b$, $b.b=b$, $b.c=a.c.b=a.b.c=(a.b).c$ and $c.c=c$ because our ring with those definitions is commutative and thus $R$  itself is an ideal.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The whole ring is always a two-sided ideal of itself, no matter whether it has a multiplicative identity or not, no matter whether it is commutative or not.

Remember that if $R$ is a ring (with or without identity), a subset $I$ of $R$ is a (two-sided) ideal if and only if

1. $I\neq\varnothing$;
2. if $a,b\in I$, then $a-b\in I$;
3. if $a\in I$ and $r\in R$, then $ra,ar\in I$.

All of these conditions are satisfied by the ring itself, $I=R$: $0\in R$ by definition of ring, proving 1; $R$ is an abelian group under addition, proving 2; and $R$ is closed under multiplication, proving 3. Thus, $R$ is a two-sided ideal of itself. It is sometimes called the *improper ideal*, because it is not a proper subset of $R$.

There is no need to consider whether $R$ has a multiplicative identity, is commutative, anything; you don't even need to worry about what it's multiplicative structure is. Whatever that structure is, $R$ is necessarily an ideal of itself.

As to your "relations" in the third paragraph (which are completely unnecessary), I don't think you have a warrant for those conclusions: consider the set $\{0,2,4,6\}$ with addition and multiplication modulo $8$; this is a ring (without identity). Note that none of $2$, $4$, or $6$ is idempotent: $2\cdot 2 = 4$, $4\cdot 4 = 0$, and $6\cdot 6 = 4$; so your claims that the elements of $R$ would necessarily be idempotent (when you assert that $aa=a$, $bb=b$, and $cc=c$ would hold) are incorrect. But again: *they are not needed*. You don't need to know what the multiplicative structure is, the whole ring is always a (two-sided) ideal of itself.

Now, if the question is meant to be "what is the largest possible number of elements a *proper* ideal can have?", then you may want to think about the fact that an ideal is necessarily a subgroup (though perhaps not all subgroups are ideals).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But if I want to find the maximum number of ideals of a ring with 4 elements, can I use for example that $R=(0,1,a,b)$ with $ab=1$ is a ring and $(a),(b),(0),(1),(ab)$ are ideals so they number is $5$?

Comment: @jut3: “Maximum number of ideals” is a completely different question. A comment is not the proper place to ask it; if you want to ask that question, then ask it in a separate post.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110875/max-number-of-ideals-in-a-ring